# Better/alternative way of phrasing this SQL query

Tags: mysql

What would be a better/more effective way of writing out the below query?

The current SQL query does its job all right but I'm concerned about the processing time as the database grows bigger.

```
SELECT *
FROM room
JOIN catering ON room.room_id = catering.room_id
WHERE capacity BETWEEN '$minCapacity' AND '$maxCapacity' 
AND room.room_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT room_id
    FROM room_booking
    WHERE date_booked = '$us_date')
AND catering.grade = '$grade' ORDER BY room.capacity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the `NOT IN` to an `NOT EXISTS`. If there is a lot of data that could increase the performance:

```
SELECT *
FROM room
JOIN catering ON room.room_id = catering.room_id
WHERE capacity BETWEEN '$minCapacity' AND '$maxCapacity' 
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        room_booking
    WHERE
        date_booked = '$us_date'
        AND room.room_id=room_booking.room_id
)
AND catering.grade = '$grade' 
ORDER BY room.capacity
```